# JQueryUI how to 'self' close a dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on a web app that uses jQueryUI and creates a ton of dialogs. The dialogs are all different, and the button to close the dialog can end up embedded several div's into the dialog.

I'd like a function that always closes the containing dialog.

Take for example the following html:

```
<div id="demoDialog">
   <div>
      <div id='demoDialogSubmit'>
         <input type='submit' onClick='selfCloseDialog();' value='Ok' style='margin-top:10px' />
      </div>
   <div>
<div>
```

Somewhere in my js code I initialized this as a dialog:

```
$( "#demoDialog" ).dialog( params );
```

Now for the on-click I have a few not so great choices. I could insist on the close button knowing the id of the dialog. E.g. do something like:

```
onclick="$( '#demoDialog' ).dialog( 'close' );"
```

But I'd rather have generic code instead of always having to carry around the id of the dialog so I can send it to a widget that may close it.

Or I can remember how many layers down I am:

```
function selfCloseDialog() { $(this).parent().dialog( 'close' ); }
```

But really I want selfCloseDialog() to just hunt up the layers of elements looking for the dialog object to close. How do I do this?

@Update:

So i got it working. Thanks everyone for their suggestions the problem actually had two issues.

First one problem was here:

```
<input type='submit' onClick='selfCloseDialog();' value='Ok'/>
```

It should be:

```
<input type='submit' onClick='selfCloseDialog(this);' value='Ok'/>
```

The button element is not passed in as the "this" argument to the function. Which seems obvious now.

And the following direct method JAAulde below works and seems the cleanest:

```
function selfCloseDialog( caller ) {
   $(caller).closest( ".ui-dialog-content" ).dialog('close');
}
```

There were several answers involving closest and a selector- but I don't see any reason to use anything except the plain class selector he suggests.

Comment: check my answer it's the one down voted. but it's exactly what you need! it will work from every where even from ajax loaded content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When making your dialog, include a close button:

```
var params = {
    //whatever you already had in there
    buttons: {
        // In the buttons object, the "key" will be the button text, the function
        // will be executed on click of the button in scope of the dialoged element
        Close: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
};

$( "#demoDialog" ).dialog( params );
```

And from code running in scope of ANY descendant element of the dialoged element, run:

```
$(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
```

Comment: Ok. But the dialog has ajax bits that come in later and may close the dialog. Particularly I have a transaction that changes the state of the dialog such that a close element appears later. That is the return of the original submit rewrites the dialog to be a confirm screen in some cases that has its own "ok" close button.

Comment: Take note of the modified answer. I edited as you were commenting.

Comment: It turned out a little differently than your second answer - but yours is closest. See edits for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm exactly understanding what you're asking, but it seems the easiest way would be to add a standard class to all your dialogs, and then have code like:

```
$(this).closest('.dialog-class').dialog('close');
```

closest() is defined here:

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: I'll try that. I think something like this is what I was looking for.

Comment: FYI, the class added by UI to all dialoged elements is `ui-dialog`, so you don't need to add any classes for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

*updated to reflect the ajax part of the dialog. *updated to reflect comments

```
<div id="soemthing.random.ui.dialog.makes">
.... your content....
<a class='custom-close' href="#Close">Custom Close</a>
.... 
</div>

$(function(){
  $("your selector").dialog();
  var selector = ":ui-dialog";
//developers choice.  ".ui-dialog-content" is faster, ":ui-dialog" is guaranteed
  $(selector ).on({
   "click":function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     $(this).closest(selector).dialog("close");
   }
  },"a.custom-close",null);

})
```

Comment: You'll want a class selector (preceded with a `.`) as opposed to a pseudo selector (preceded by a `:`) for that dialog class.

Comment: :ui-dialog works, but is slower as far as selectors goes.  its a last resort of any widget compliant with the $.widget() factory

Comment: @DefyGravity the `:ui-dialog` option is quite clean IMO, should be added to the answer.

Comment: @DefyGravity agreed that it works, but is slower. Since UI adds the class to every dialoged element, it is faster to query with it. Good call on the edit.

Comment: Sorry, `ui-dialog` is not the class you want to use. It's actually `ui-dialog-content`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a class instead of writing inline function calls, but that's up to you.

Here's my hackish solution with event delegation where clicking an element with the `selfclose` class will close the ancestor dialog:

```
$(document).on('click', '.selfclose', function() {
    $(this).parents().each(function() {
        try {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        } catch(e) {}
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bAzab/2/)

But as DefyGravity mentioned, using the `:ui-dialog` selector is a much cleaner solution:

```
$(document).on('click', '.selfclose', function() {
    $(this).closest(":ui-dialog").dialog("close");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bAzab/4/)

Comment: It is *not* cleaner to use the pseudo selector. UI adds the class `ui-dialog` to all elements which get dialoged (that is, elements which have `.dialog()` called on them), so it is a faster query to use a class selector as opposed to a pseudo.

Comment: @JAAulde I've read your comment in the other answer prior to posting this answer, and your suggestion unfortunately didn't work on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bAzab/5/).

Comment: I apologize, the element which had dialog called on it receives the `ui-dialog-content` class. The class which I mentioned before is assigned to the outer wrapper of the elements UI creates to wrap around the dialoged element. http://jsfiddle.net/bAzab/6/

Comment: @JAAulde You should post that as an answer I guess, it's a pretty effective way when fraction of milliseconds are concerned. `=]`

Comment: lol, about the saving milliseconds. Anyway, I posted it as an edit to the first answer to the question before any other answers were posted.

Comment: Didn't see it before, +1 now =]

Answer (score -1):

check this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wqh4Y/3/

```
function closeParentDialog(closeButton)
{
closeButton.parents('.ui-dialog').eq(0).find('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').eq(0).click();

}

$(function() {


    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();

});​
```

you can use it like this:

```
     <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog   window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.

          <span> <a class="close-dialog" onclick="closeParentDialog($(this))">selfclose</a>  </span>
        </p>
     </div>
```

Comment: No offense, but this should not be followed. jQuery UI provides a very clean API which should be used. Do not mimic user interaction to accomplish what a clean API call would do.

Comment: i agree, but sometimes the api is not enough, and here is example of one of this times when you need to "remove the glove"

Comment: No, this is not an example which is "one of those times".